# How to avoid this bug in Scrutinizer for Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scrutinizer

When I check my Laravel app on [Scrutinizer](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/pacoorozco/probind/issues/develop/files/app/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.php?orderField=path&order=asc&honorSelectedPaths=0) shows me some bugs like this one:

```
The method with does only exist in Illuminate\View\View, but not in Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory.
```

The code is:

```
$data['records'] = Record::all()->count();
$data['users'] = User::all()->count();

return view('dashboard.index')
        ->with('data', $data);
```

It works perfect, but on every analisys it shows me the same error.  I think is a problem with my `View` class instantation but I don't know how to solve it.

Is there any good guide to configure Scrutinizer for Laravel projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution of it?